# I want to compare current time with string time1 and time2 in 24 hour format

Tags: javascript

I am not able to compare the current time with strings time1 and time2.

I have written a javascript code but it is returning false output.

```
const time1 = '08:00';
const time2 = '17:00';
const time3 = new Date().toLocaleTimeString([], {
    hour: '2-digit  ',
    minute: "2-digit",
    hour12: false
});

if (time1 < time3 && time3 < time2) {

    function addHours(date, hours) {
        date.setHours(date.getHours() + hours);

        return date;
    }

    const d = new Date();
    const date = new Date(d);

    const newDate = addHours(date, 1);

    console.log(newDate);
    alert('Yours Scheduled time is ' + newDate);
} else
    alert('You cannnot get appointment now ');
```

Answer (score 0):

In your approach first `time1 < time3` will be converted to a `Boolean` and then you are comparing `Boolean < time2` which doesn't work.

You need to change your condition to this:

```
if(time1 < time3 && time3 < time2) {}
```

Comment: But the time1 and time2 are in string format and current time is in integer how it compares

Comment: time3 is not an integer. You are creating a string with toLocaleTimeString function call.